# Code inside listener for button doesn't get executed

Tags: java, android, button

I have the following ButtonListener:

```java
 final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
            // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
            if (!isRunning) {
                Log.i("Button", "Starting");
                if (!hasScannedNFC) {
                    GUIHelper.showNFCScanRequest(ArIndoorNav.this);
                } else {
                    /**
                     * Read out text field. Get coordinates for destination. Calculate initial path with PathSolver.
                     * Set new running flag. Start loop in OnDrawFrame.
                     */
                    EditText et = findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    Log.i("Button", "Test");
                    Log.i("Button", et.getText().toString());

                    PathSolver.getPath("0.0", et.getText().toString());

                    button.setText("Stop");
                    isRunning = true;
                }
            } else {
                Log.i("Button", "Stopping");
                button.setText("Start");
                isRunning = false;
            }
        });
```

The `button.setText()` gets executed, however none of the other statements like the Log commands. Why is that? The code is located in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Try adding breakpoints to your code and debugging. You might find that a value you expected to be there and populated isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed to be a problem with Android Studio. New changes weren't applied while building. A restart and Clean & Build fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

First check these steps in Logcat:

1. Correct device is connected
2. Correct debuggable processes is selected
3. "Show only selected application" is selected

If all of these are ok and also command not showing in Logcat then change your Log.i() method with Log.d() and try again.